# Is it necessary to escape parameters for stored procedures?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli, escaping

Or the call to real_escape_string() in such cases is not needed?
/Email value comes from user input./

```
function findUser($email)  
{   
    $mysqli = connectDB();  
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($email);  
    $query = "CALL FindUser('{$email}')";  
    // ...  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just building a dynamic SQL string that contains a procedure call, which can be attacked.  You should bind parameters to the procedure, which gives you some protection, as long as you do not use dynamic SQL within the procedure.

[mysqli_stmt::bind_param](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

[Bound Parameters](http://devzone.zend.com/article/686#Heading11)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you still need to escape it, the stored procedure is just as vulnerable as a regular query.

Comment: I thought parameters for stored procedures will be automatically escaped by the database.

Comment: You would with numbers where you can declare their type, but strings like an email could still be injected against. Consider if they sent the below as their email:
    email@email.com');DROP TABLE USERS;

You're probably thinking of parameter binding, like KM was talking about. That's really the safest way to do it. Takes all the fear out of wondering if you missed a mysql_real_escape_string call somewhere.